# Who are the immortals(semi) mentioned in our scriptures?

Tags: history, scripture

I heard that there are 7 (or 8) immortals mentioned in our scriptures like *Hanuman* and *Ashvathaman*, I know only two of them, and I want to know others, with their brief enlightenment.

I used the word 'semi' as I wasn't able to find a word to describe personnel who's age is limited to a *'Mahayug'*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Chiranjivi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiranjivi).

List of the seven immortals are as below,

1. Ashwatthama, the son of Drona.
2. Bali, also called MahaBali, was the virtuous emperor of the three worlds and grandson of Prahlad
3. Hanuman, served Rama. He stands for selflessness, courage, devotion, strength, and righteous conduct.
4. Kripa, military guru of the princes in the Mahabharata.
5. Parashurama, 6th avatar of Vishnu,
6. Vibhishana, brother of Ravana.
7. Vyasa, the sage who composed the Mahabharata.

Hindu scripture contains a mantra about the seven immortals, in which their names are recited for luck and longevity:

अश्वत्थामाबलिर्व्यासोहनुमांश्च विभीषण:कृपश्चपरशुरामश्च सप्तैतेचिरंजीविन:।

> Ashwathaama Balir Vyasaha Hanumantha Vibeeshanaha
>   Kripa Parashuramascha
>   Saptaitey Chiranjivinaha

Apart from the seven Chiranjivis above mentioned, there exist other Chiranjivis as well. For instance, Sage Markandeya, when at the age of sixteen, was blessed with immortality.
Other immortals or Chiranjivins. Jambavan, Markandeya, Devapi, Maru, Saptarishis, Bhusunda (Crow), Alha and Udal.

Comment: can you provide how they got immortality, with a brief story, this will make it more clear to me.

Comment: @KCloud -If you want stories you have to read it on your own, it is not possible here.

Comment: @Creator, my bad, I actually got the stories when someone posted the question duplicate, thanks.